# SQL wildcard charlist using PHP PDO statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, wildcard

I created a form that will send the value of search range to the database, but it seems not to be working.

The query:

```
$alpha = $_POST['alpha'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_members WHERE resultselect=? AND lname LIKE ?;";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($categoryid,"[".$alpha."]%"));
```

The form:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <button class="btn btn-link" value="abc" name="alpha">A-B-C</button>
    <button class="btn btn-link" value="def" name="alpha">D-E-F</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (MySql, SQL Server, Oracle ...)?

Comment: I am making use of mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Mysql you can use [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

```php
$alpha = $_POST['alpha'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_members WHERE resultselect=? AND lname REGEXP ?;";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($categoryid,"^[".$alpha."]"));
```

With [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) your query should look like

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl_members 
WHERE resultselect=? 
  AND (lname LIKE 'a%'
   OR  lname LIKE 'b%'
   OR  lname LIKE 'c%')
```

Therefore your php code in that case might be (assuming that you always search using three characters)

```php
$alpha = $_POST['alpha'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_members 
        WHERE resultselect=? AND lname (lname LIKE ? OR  lname LIKE ? OR  lname LIKE ?);";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($categoryid, $alpha[0].'%', $alpha[1].'%', $alpha[2].'%'));
```

To order resultset alphabetically use [`ORDER BY lname`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52064/1)** demo for both `LIKE` and `REGEXP`

Comment: thanks peterm. I am want the result to be based on alphabetically display of names. I am still a newbie in mysql.what is the difference between the REGEXP and the LIKE cos the like seems to give me what I want.

Comment: Also I tried it with the like and regexp but it seems not to be displaying the result set in the alphabetically order.

Comment: @CharlesOkaformbah See updated answer for links to documentation for both `LIKE` and `REGEXP` and a sqlfiddle demo. Ultimately both are means for pattern matching, but `LIKE` is very basic and limited to only two wildcards `%` and '_'. With `REGEXP` you can utilize more sophisticated regular expressions. It's your choice what to use. I gave examples for both. In the end results will be the same.

Comment: @CharlesOkaformbah In order to order results you need to use `ORDER BY` clause and it has nothing to do with `LIKE` or `REGEXP`. Your query posted in the question lacks it. Therefore just add ` ORDER BY lname` at the end of your query.

Comment: @CharlesOkaformbah Updated sqlfiddle to show use of `ORDER BY`

Comment: @CharlesOkaformbah Do you need more help with your original question?